# Avoid webmail redirection

Tags: heroku, flask, webmail

I have settled my domain and my app is running perfectly on Heroku with Flask. The problem is, my hosting (that only owns the domain) points the webmail as mydomain.com/webmail. But, my application thinks this URL is proper from the script and when it tries to load it, it gives a 404 error.

I've looked around and in the CPanel forum says I should add this:

```
ScriptAlias /webmail /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi
ScriptAliasMatch ^/webmail/(.*) /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/wredirect.cgi
```

to the **httpd.conf** file, which I don't know where to locate. Is there any way around this?